# twig error when using in slim

Tags: twig, slim

Hi I need interate twig to Slim application, I install twig with composer and im my script I have

```
<?php

use Slim\Slim;
use Slim\Views\Twig;

use Noodlehaus\Config;

use Codecourse\User\User;

session_cache_limiter(false);
session_start();

ini_set('display_errors','On');

define('INC_ROOT', dirname(__DIR__));

require INC_ROOT.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Slim([
    'mode' => file_get_contents(INC_ROOT.'/mode.php'),
    'view' => new Twig(),
    'template.path' => INC_ROOT . '/app/views'
]);
$app->view->setTemplatesDirectory("/views");

$app->configureMode($app->config('mode'), function() use ($app) {
    $app->config = Config::load(INC_ROOT . "/app/config/{$app->mode}.php");
});



echo $app->config->get('db.driver');

require 'database.php';

$app->container->set('user', function() {
    return new User;
});

$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    $app->render('home.php');
});
```

when I run script I obtain this error:

> Type: Twig_Error_Loader
>
> Message: The "/views" directory does not exist.
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\authentication\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php

Comment: Well it sounds like you're missing a 'views' directory.  Have you created the directory?  Is that the correct filepath, should it be `/app/views` instead?

Comment: Yes I have created directory /app/views.

Comment: You mean use `$app->view->setTemplatesDirectory("/app/views")` this product the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My stupid mistake

i must use

```
'templates.path' => INC_ROOT . '/app/views'
```

and I have

```
'template.path' => INC_ROOT . '/app/views'
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Slim documentation for configuring the template path](http://docs.slimframework.com/configuration/settings/#templatespath) might be a little misleading; you only need to set `template.path` or call `View::setTemplatesDirectory` but not both.

If you wanted to use the latter, then it would simply be :

```
$app->view->setTemplatesDirectory(INC_ROOT . '/app/views');
```

Comment: when I comment the row `$app->view->setTemplatesDirectory("/views"); `then I have same error

Comment: @mardon interesting, it's not being cached anywhere?

Comment: I think Its not being cached